# On the production mode, phpmyadmin does not find the static files when it is served by a Ngnix

Tags: docker, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have a [docker compose file](https://github.com/rmmariano/test-nginx-phpmyadmin/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) with a Nginx and phpmyadmin services.

I would like to create a location on my Nginx service that points to my phpmyadmin service.

For example:

- Location on Nginx         ->  phpmyadmin
- "/phpmyadmin"             ->  "/"
- "/phpmyadmin/index.php"   -> "/index.php"
- "/phpmyadmin/sql.php"     ->  "/sql.php"
- etc.

I've added the [following settings](https://github.com/rmmariano/test-nginx-phpmyadmin/blob/master/volumes/nginx/nginx.template#L18) to my Nginx service:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

When I try to open phpmyadmin on my browser on my own machine, the settings work, however when I use the same seetings on my online server, phpmyadmin is not able to find the static files (e.g. js and css files). I've shared an example below.

I've tried to set the `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI` variable, but phpmyadmin seems to ignore it. Even with this environment variable set, phpmyadmin looks for the static files on the "/" instead of "/phpmyadmin".

I've added an example [here](https://github.com/rmmariano/test-nginx-phpmyadmin). To use it, user should remove the "EXAMPLE" suffix from the [environment files](https://github.com/rmmariano/test-nginx-phpmyadmin/tree/master/env_files).

Thank you in advance.

**Error messages:**

On the server, phpmyadmin looks for the static files on the root path (e.g. "http://www2.example.com/js/...") instead of the defined location (e.g. "http://www2.example.com/phpmyadmin/js/..."). I've set `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI` to "http://www2.example.com/phpmyadmin".

```
The resource from “http://www2.example.com/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

The resource from “http://www2.example.com/js/vendor/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css?v=5.0.1” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

The resource from “http://www2.example.com/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css?v=5.0.1” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/101#issuecomment-267541779) information would help you?

Comment: Thank you. This information helped me.